# p_load leads to Failed to install/load: lubridate, shiny, rio

Tags: r, shiny, package, r-rio

Trying to start up a new project in a rMarkdown file. I've been able to load these packages in the past, but since about a week ago I haven't been able to load the packages rio, lubridate, and and shiny.

Here's my code

```
library(pacman)
p_load(dplyr, tidyr, stringr, lubridate, httr, ggplot2, shiny, rio, rmarkdown, knitr)
```

This yields

```
Installing package into ‘/Users/danieltheng/Library/R/4.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/lubridate_1.7.9.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1545879 bytes (1.5 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.5 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/n6/wywrh17x6cjfkjx3qdpdd50m0000gn/T//Rtmp079VS6/downloaded_packages

lubridate installed
package ‘lubridate’ was built under R version 4.0.2Installing package into ‘/Users/danieltheng/Library/R/4.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/shiny_1.5.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5307401 bytes (5.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 5.1 MB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/n6/wywrh17x6cjfkjx3qdpdd50m0000gn/T//Rtmp079VS6/downloaded_packages

shiny installed
package ‘shiny’ was built under R version 4.0.2Installing package into ‘/Users/danieltheng/Library/R/4.0/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/4.0/rio_0.5.16.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 503445 bytes (491 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 491 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/n6/wywrh17x6cjfkjx3qdpdd50m0000gn/T//Rtmp079VS6/downloaded_packages

rio installed
package ‘rio’ was built under R version 4.0.2Failed to install/load:
lubridate, shiny, rio
```

When I try to load rio from library(rio)

```
library(rio)
```

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rio’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘rio’ was built under R version 4.0.2
```

Has anyone encountered an issue like this?

Comment: What R version and which OS version are you running? R 4.0 requires macOS 10.13 or higher. I've seen a similar error when people were trying to use it on an older OS version.

Comment: macOS 10.15.4 and R version 4.0.0.

Comment: After reading your comment, I updated my R version to 4.0.2 and now the packages load correctly. Thank you!

Comment: I am with MRO 3.5.3, also hv same problem.